# detecting end of call and generating a pop-up message in xamarin forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

guys, I've already created a working code that is in my incomingCallReceiver.droid that detects the end of the call and displays the message in
my console, however, I'm not able to display a pop-up as using AlertDialog,DisplayAlert,MessageBox.show() all seem to not work.

so I was wondering if there was a way around this:-

```
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            if (intent != null && intent.Action.Equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"))
            {
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoign call", 1000).show();
                String number = intent.GetStringExtra(Intent.ExtraPhoneNumber);
            }
            else
            {
                //get the phone state
                String newPhoneState = intent.HasExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState) ? intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState) : null;
                Bundle bundle = intent.Extras;

                if (newPhoneState != null && newPhoneState.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging))
                {
                    //read the incoming call number
                    String phoneNumber = bundle.GetString(TelephonyManager.ExtraIncomingNumber);
                    //Log.i("PHONE RECEIVER", "Telephone is now ringing " + phoneNumber);

                }
                else if (newPhoneState != null && newPhoneState.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle))
                {
                    //Once the call ends, phone will become idle
                    //Log.i("PHONE RECEIVER", "Telephone is now idle");

                    Console.WriteLine("call ended");
                    //DisplayAlert("Alert", "CALL RECIEVED", "OK");

                }
                else if (newPhoneState != null && newPhoneState.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook))
                {
                    //Once you receive call, phone is busy
                    //Log.i("PHONE RECEIVER", "Telephone is now busy");
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Log.i("Telephony receiver", ee.getMessage());
        }

    }

    private void DisplayAlert(string v1, string v2, string v3)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try doing it on UI thread? Something like this:

```
var _activityContext = (Activity) context;
Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(_activityContext);  
AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();  
alert.SetTitle("Title");  
alert.SetMessage("Simple Alert");  
alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>  
{  
// Ok button click task  
});  
_activityContext.RunOnUiThread(() => { 

alert.Show(); 
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but i tried it out it doesn't work. do i need to create a reference elsewhere maybe in the MainActivity.cs file?

Comment: if (state.Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle))
                { Console.WriteLine("call has ended");
                  `  Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    AlertDialog alert = dialog.Create();
                    alert.SetTitle("Title");
                    alert.SetMessage("Simple Alert");
                    alert.SetButton("OK", (c, ev) =>
                    { context.RunOnUiThread(() => { alert.Show();});}}}`

Comment: context doesn't contain a definition of runOnUiThread and no extension method "RunOnUiThread" accepting a first argument of type context could be found

Comment: Its because you need activity instance, anyway i have done it for you take a look